# How to draw the distance between 2 points on an image with React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Me and my team have been developing a software that among other things **takes measures on pictures**, as you can see in this animation.

[image: Preview]

Now we've been asked to **make a mobile app** with a subset of the desktop features, including the measuring tool.
We decided to use **React Native**, because we're a small team and we don't have the resources to maintain 2 codebases.
Also I prefer cross-platform tools, which is why we developed our package with Qt and Python.

Unfortunately we are quite inexperienced with mobile development and don't really know which packages and libraries are best suited to implement this.
*Ergo I bring forth my question in this sanctuary of collective knowledge*

### What do you suggest to replicate this functionality?

On the desktop side we're using [PyQtGraph](https://www.pyqtgraph.org/), but I didn't find anything like it for React Native.
We have a half baked prototype with [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg), but it's **dead slow**, because SVGs are not the right tool for the job.
I'm sure there is a faster way to do it, I just don't know it yet. *Please teach me the ways of RN*

Here is a working example of the python implementation:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljl0dytahbl6dga/MeasureView.zip?dl=0